# Event listeners executing without event and looping through HTML collection

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop, addeventlistener

I am trying to write a loop to initialize event handlers in JavaScript.

I think I am doing something wrong, because my debugging function is being activated without the event (the click) occurring.

What I want to do is this:

```
var JS_elements = document.getElementsByClassName("JS")

for (y = 0; y < JS_elements.length; y++){
    document.write(JS_elements.item(y).innerHTML);
    JS_elements.item(y).addEventListener("click",testfunc());
}

function testfunc() {
    alert("TestFunc");
}
```

and have testfunc() run when I click on an element with a class="JS".

The line `document.write(JS_elements.item(y).innerHTML);` line executes correctly, so I know I am getting to the correct objects. Sadly, the commented line is causing this to break: testfunc() runs three times automatically on the page load.

Can anyone explain why this is happening? The only thing I can think is that "click" is being evaluated as `true` for some reason.

HTML:

```
<header>
    <hr>
        <p>- Header Background Color Controller -</p>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Javascript Controller:</td>
                <td class="JS">Red
                    <input type="hidden" value='false'>
                </td>
                <td class="JS">Green
                    <input type="hidden" value='false'>
                </td>
                <td class="JS">Blue
                    <input type="hidden" value='false'>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>jQuery Controller:</td>
                <td class="jQ" value=false>Red</td>
                <td class="jQ" value=false>Green</td>
                <td class="jQ" value=false>Blue</td>
            <tr>
        </table>
    <hr>
</header>
```

Comment: Are you aware what `()` after a function name does? `testfunc` doesn't return a function, why to call it when setting an event listener?

Comment: I'm just using `testfunc()` for debugging.

Comment: Please show the real code you have. Notice, that `document.write` will break the code anyway, if it's executed after the page has been parsed.

Comment: This is the real code I have.

Comment: Then please re-read my first comment.

Comment: Does the function I am trying to call with the event listeners have some bearing on this issue? I'm trying to figure out <em>why</em> `testfunc()` is being executed three times when the page loads (without any clicks).

Comment: The issue isn't the function you're trying to call, the issue is you included `()` after the function name in this syntax: `JS_elements.item(y).addEventListener("click",testfunc());`, you need to remove the `()` as described in @jfriend00 's answer below.

Comment: Yes, it does. There's a big difference between function call and a reference to a function, which is what [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) is waiting for.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change this:

```
JS_elements.item(y).addEventListener("click",testfunc());
```

to this:

```
JS_elements.item(y).addEventListener("click",testfunc);
```

The `()` causes the function to be executed immediately and the return result is passed to `addEventListener()`.  That is not what you want.  Instead, you want to pass a function reference which should be just the name of the function `testfunc` without the `()` after it.

---

If you want to pass arguments to `testfunc` and they are the same arguments for all the event handlers, then you can create an intermediary anonymous function:

```
JS_elements.item(y).addEventListener("click",function() {
    testfunc("whatever");
});
```

Comment: Now for my next dilemma: how to call a function that does take arguments?

Comment: @BrandonHastings - you'd have to show us exactly what you're trying to pass to it and whether you're trying to pass the same thing to every event handler for each time or not.  There are a variety of ways to solve that issue depending upon the situation.

Comment: @BrandonHastings - I added one example of arguments on `testfunc` to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Just do this:
`JS_elements.item(y).addEventListener("click",testfunc);`